# Explain commented lines in the body

Tags: c

```
typedef union
{
      float f;
      struct
      {
            //unsigned int mantissa : 23;
            //unsigned int exponent : 8;
            //unsigned int sign : 1;
       } field;
} myfloat;
```

I came across these lines in this code. What to they mean?

Comment: A bunch of commented lines. Meaning someone have changed their mind.

Comment: What about them specifically are you asking about? They're commented out members of the struct.

Comment: Presumably its nothing but an empty struct. Those lines are commented out and are not read by the compiler.

Comment: Read good artical : https://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm&ei=1pzU3MO-&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=143&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1486055062&sig=AF9NedmX5JZdKoCh_cSywfxitAEnx7x3Hg

Comment: Comments, by definition, are ignored by the compiler. Are you asking what would they mean if they weren't commented?

Answer (score 1):

The commented lines are members using [bitfields](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field). The number after the colon determines the number of bits that the member would use.

Since the struct they are contained in forms a union with a `float`, they are likely an attempt by somebody to inspect the components of the member `f`, as a [single precision IEEE-754 floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32), which uses 23 bits of mantissa, 8 bits for the exponent and 1 bit for the sign.

Answer (score 0):

Those commented out lines are the names and lengths of the different sections of bits in a float. What is this code from/what is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: Must a `float` be an IEEE 754 32-bit base-2 floating-point number?